# show cms pages in header navigation magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, show

Hi I need in my project to show the CMS pages link dynamically in header,

Can anybody suggest me How I can do this ?

Comment: This might helps you http://www.codegyan.com/2012/02/11/add-cms-pages-in-top-navigation-in-magento/

Comment: yes it works fine and easy to implement but it doesnot work in top.phtml
i have place the code in header file and it works fine here

Comment: Great. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: yes it will realy help me thanks you save my lot of time

Comment: do you also know somwthing about year,modal functionality for spare car parts site

Comment: Not sure. Post new question with your details. May other fellows could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**with** this **code** we **can** show **magento** cms page **dynamically** in magento navigation 
which have status enabled. We just need to **place** this code in **header** or in **topnav** file

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());?>
<?php  $collection->getSelect()->where('is_active = 1'); ?>
<ul id="nav">
<?php foreach ($collection as $page): ?>
<?php $PageData = $page->getData(); ?>
<?php// print_r($PageData);?>
<?php if($PageData['identifier']!='no-route' && $PageData['identifier']!='enable-cookies' && $PageData['identifier']!='home2') { ?>
<li>
<a href="/magento/index.php/<?php echo $PageData['identifier']?>"><span><?php echo $PageData['title'] ?></span></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```